# Integrating probabilities

Tags: probability, integration, stochastic-processes

My following problem is of general nature, here is an example to illustrate it.

For example let $\left(\xi_i\right)_{i \geq 1}$ be independent and identically Exp(1) distributed random variables. We define for $t\geq 0$,
$$ X\left(t\right) = \max \left\{n\geq 0: \sum_{k=1}^n \xi_k \leq t \right\}. $$
Of course $S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n \xi_k $ is $\Gamma\left(1,n\right)$ distributed. One want's to show that $X\left(t\right)$ is a Poisson-Prozess and calculates $P\left(X\left(t\right)=n\right)= P\left(S_n \leq t, S_{n+1} > t \right) = P\left(S_n \leq t, S_n + \xi_{n+1} > t \right).$ Now the following kind of transformation, I never get (because this is no usual $\sigma$-addidivity)

$$ P\left(S_n \leq t, S_n + \xi_{n+1} > t \right) = \int_0^t f_{S_n}\left(y\right) P\left(\xi_{n+1} > t-y \right) \text{d}y. $$

($f_{S_n}$ is of course the density of $S_n$) Could someone explain it, to me, why these expressions are equal??

A similar problem is also. Suppose $\left(X\left(t\right)\right)_{t \geq 0}$ is a continous time Markov process with values in a countable set $E$ with right-continous sample paths. I know already that the time spent in each state $i \in E$ (before transitioning to some other state) is exponentially distributed with some parameter $q\left(i\right) \geq 0.$ With the definition $\omega\left(j\right) = \inf \left\{t > 0: X\left(t\right)=j, X\left(t-0\right) \neq j \right\}$, I want to show for $i \neq j$, that $ P_i \left(X\left(t\right) = j \right) >0 $ if and only if $ P_i\left(\omega\left(j\right) \leq t \right) > 0. $ Now why can you just do some calculation like the following

\begin{align*}
P_i\left(X\left(t\right) = j \right) &= \int_0^t P_i\left(X\left(t\right) = j, \omega\left(j\right) = \text{d}s\right) \\
&\geq P_i\left(X\left(u\right) = j \text{ for all } u \in \left[ds,t\right] | X\left(ds\right) = j \right) \cdot P_i\left(\omega\left(j\right) = \text{d}s \right) \\
&\geq e^{-q\left(j\right)t} \cdot P_i\left(\omega\left(j\right) \leq t \right) > 0.
\end{align*}

Particularly in the second case, it's not clear to me, if you go to the definition of the Lebesgue-integral how you can apply the Markov-property in a clean way.

For answers, I would be very happy and grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Re your first question, note that for every independent random variables $(X,Y)$, $X$ with density $f$, and every events $(A,B)$, $$P(X\in A,X+Y\in B)=\int_Af(x)P(Y+x\in B)\mathrm dx.$$ To show this, note that, in full generality, $$P(X\in A,X+Y\in B)=\iint \mathbf 1_{x\in A}\mathbf 1_{x+y\in B}\mathrm dP_{(X,Y)}(x,y),$$ hence, by the independence of $(X,Y)$, $$P(X\in A,X+Y\in B)=\int \mathbf 1_{x\in A}\left(\int\mathbf 1_{x+y\in B}\mathrm dP_Y(y)\right)\mathrm dP_X(x).$$ The inner parenthesis is $P(x+Y\in B)$ and $P_X$ has density $f$ hence the proof is complete.

Re your second question, there are some serious misprints in your computations, but, considering the hitting time $T_j$ of $j$ (your $\omega(j)$), one has $$P_i(X_t=j)=P_i(X_t=j,T_j\leqslant t)=\int_0^tP_i(X_t=j\mid T_j=s)\mathrm dP_{T_j}(s).$$ For every $s\leqslant t$, $$P_i(X_t=j\mid T_j=s)\geqslant P_i(\forall u\in[s,t],X_u=j\mid T_j=s).$$ The Markov property at time $s$ indicates that the RHS is equal to $$P_j(\forall u\in[0,t-s],X_u=j)=\mathrm e^{-q(j)(t-s)}\geqslant\mathrm e^{-q(j)t},$$ hence $$P_i(X_t=j)\geqslant\int_0^t\mathrm e^{-q(j)t}\mathrm dP_{T_j}(s)=\mathrm e^{-q(j)t}P(T_j\leqslant t).$$

Comment: Hi Did, great thanks for your answer. I'm fully happy with your explanation of my first problem. But in the second case, i don't understand why you can calculate $$P_i(X_t=j)=P_i(X_t=j,T_j\leqslant t)=\int_0^tP_i(X_t=j\mid T_j=s)\mathrm dP_{T_j}(s).$$ In particular, for me $P_i(X_t=j\mid T_j=s)$ is not defined, because $P_i\left(T_j = s \right) = 0.$ I know of the course the definition if $X,Y$ are random variables then $E\left[X|Y \right] = g\left(Y\right)$ for some measurable $g$ and then $E\left[X|Y = y \right] = g\left(y\right).$, but i dont't know how to calculate with this.

Comment: This follows from $P_i(X_t=j)=E_i(u(T_j))$ with $u(T_j)=P_i(X_t=j\mid T_j)$ thus $u(s)=0$ for $s\gt t$ and, for $s\lt t$, $P_i(X_t=j\mid T_j=s)$ in the integral represents $u(s)$. Note finally that $E_i(u(T_j))=\displaystyle\int u(s)\mathrm dP_{T_j}(s)$. (Unrelated: I suggest to delete your first comment, the errors you made typing it are ruining the alignment of the page and currently *hiding* part of the present comment.)

Comment: I still don't get why you can determine $u$ by calculating $u\left(s\right) = P_i\left(X\left(t\right) = j |T_j = s\right)$ as you did (because the right hand side is defined through the left side) For me, one has to determine $u$ by u is something measurable, s.t. $P_i\left(X_t = j, B\right) = E_i\left[u\left(T_j\right) \textbf{1}_B \right]$ for all $B \in \sigma\left(T_j\right).$ How can you follow from that definition that $u\left(T_j\right) \geq e^{-q\left(j\right) t}$ on $\left\{ T_j \leq t \right\}$ ??

Comment: One does not need to compute $u$, only to compare it to something easy to evaluate. If $P_i(X_t=j\mid T_j)=u(T_j)$ and $P_i(\forall r\in(T_j,t),X_r=j\mid T_j)=v(T_j)$ then $u\geqslant v$. Now, by the Markov property at time $T_j$,  $v(s)=P_i(\forall r\in(s,t),X_r=j\mid X_s=j)=e^{-q(j)(t-s)}$ for every $s$ in $(0,t)$ hence we are done.

Comment: Ok,I found out,\begin{align*}u\left(T_j\right)&=E\left[ \textbf{1}_{\lbrace X_t = j\rbrace}|T_j \right]\\&\geq E\left[\textbf{1}_{\lbrace X_t = j\rbrace}\textbf{1}_{\lbrace T_j\leq t\rbrace}|T_j\right]\\&\geq E\left[\textbf{1}_{\lbrace X_s = j \forall s \in \left[T_j, t\right] \rbrace}|T_j \right] \textbf{1}_{\lbrace T_j \leq t\rbrace}\\&\geq E\left[\textbf{1}_{\lbrace X_s = j \forall s \in \left[T_j, T_j+t\right] \rbrace} |T_j\right] \textbf{1}_{\lbrace T_j \leq t\rbrace} \\&= e^{-q\left(j\right)t} \textbf{1}_{\lbrace T_j \leq t\rbrace}\end{align*} with the strong Markov property applied.